# Debugging Using Xdebug Static Functions

Tags: php, xdebug, breakpoints

I am using `xdebug` on a `Laravel` application.  When I set breakpoints on static functions, the program behaves unexpectedly.  I searched the web and found that this can sometimes be an issue, so I stopped setting breakpoints on any static functions.  However, this problem started to manifest itself again.

I would setup a breakpoint on the controller. The application would stop on the breakpoint, and then I would continue.  The web page would then display blank, or some unexpected error.  However, if I ran the application without the breakpoint it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else encounters this same issue. I had added watch statements for variables inside of static functions.  Once I removed the watch statements, I was then able to use breakpoints, without the application miss-behaving.